# Rules Pattern on Object Change

Tags: c#, design-patterns, rule-engine

I have a system that lets people create and work with Orders. Orders can have multiple Steps. The Order can have a status of New, InProgress, Done, and Cancelled.

There are a bunch of business rules on what can and can't be done. Examples of rules are "can only add/remove Steps to an Order if the Order is New", "can't move an Order to Cancelled if any Step has a Cost>0", and "the Order must have Approved=true to move from New to InProgress".

I'm trying to find a good way to enforce these rules, other than several if statements splattered all around the code. I saw the Rules design pattern, but everything I can find on that applies to a single object state, and not a change in the object.

My current approach is this. I have a bunch of `IRules`. Each one has a `Validate(Order source, Order destination)` method that validates that the transition is allowed by its rule. Each endpoint in my API loads the current Order, creates a new Order with the change made, then calls a method that runs all the rules.

Am I going about this wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are working on a "State Machine"
you must store your current status  enum {New, InProgress}
you receive some events, you handle the event and apply some actions by respecting rules corresponding to the current status ( and eventually with some memory about the previous status)

Answer (score 0):

The best way here is to use a State-Pattern(specific pattern in GoF patterns). State pattern helps you to encapsulate your state according to your business and then do whatever you want according to the internal state.

Your example actually is a [Finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)  that can be in exactly one of a finite number of states at any given time.
[image]

So in this case instead of lots of If-Else or Switch-case you can use state pattern. The State pattern suggests that you create new classes for all possible states of an object and extract all state-specific behaviors into these classes.

[image]

For more information you can read this [great site](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state) and also for real example in C# please have a look [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state/csharp/example) .